# How to create a job in hudson for UCM clearcase

Tags: hudson, clearcase, jenkins

I am new to hudson can anyone explain how to configure a job in Hudson on a stream (UCM ClearCase)

1. I want to setup a job on UCM stream in Hudson
2. Want to execute a simple `build.sh` which is under `<component>/build/build.sh`
3. The o/p is available under `<component>/release/` directory
4. want to copy the contents under release dir to another location on same server say `/tmp/xyz`

I am not understanding how Hudson is creating view where and how can I tell Hudson to execute my `build.sh`.
How does it know it is under the right dir to execute the `build.sh`?

Can someone please explain would be a great help

Than

Answer (score 1):

The main parameter is the `Stream Selector` field (if you have added the **[ClearCase plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clearcase+Plugin)**):

Once you have put a Stream name in that field:

- a snapshot view will be created, referencing that UCM Stream.
  If the view was already created, it will simply be started.
- your script will be executed on any changes detected in that view (`lshistory`), or, if you want, every n minutes.
- your `build.sh` must be added as a step in the build section: "Add build step / execute shell".
  That means you have chosen **`Build a free-style software project`** when creating a new Job.
  Each step allows you to define the execution directory and script you want to run.